# Content-dependent templates/partials with moustache.js

Tags: javascript, templates

I'd like to use [moustache.js](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to render the following JSON structure:

```
[
  {type:'img', src:'some_url'},
  {type:'text', text:'lorem ipsum ...'},
  {type:'link', href:'some_url', label:'click here'},
  //  more entries ...
]
```

I'd like to render each item depending on type: img should br rendered as `<img src="{{src}}">`, text as `<p>{{text}}</p>`, etc. Is that possible with moustache.js or should I roll my own templating system? If it's possible, how would the template look like and how must I extend the JSON structure that it works as a moustache view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's absolutely possible.

You could do something like

```
{{#myarray}} {{! loop through array}}
{{#src}} {{! if you have src it must be an img}}
  <img src="{{src}}">
{{/src}}  
{{#text}} {{! if you have text is must be a paragraph}}
  <p>{{text}}{{/p}}
{{/text}}
{{#href}}} {{! if you have an href is must be an anchor}}
  <a href="{{href}}">{{label}}</a>
{{/href}}
{{/myarray}}
```

No reason to extend the json at all, as long as the fields are unique to a certain type of output. You can just check if the field exists, and then if it does it must be output in a certain way.

The other thing you can do instead of having a 'type' field is have the json set with various flags to base you're template on (e.g. 'is_image: true', 'is_anchor: true', etc).